# Chrome extension pop up opened event listener in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first chrome extension and I'm trying to create a pop up extension that scrapes a webpage and add some items to a list, based on the results. Kind of like a wishlist.

I want to listen to a popup opened event in my content script so I can re-scrape the webpage for updated data (that's if the user clicks something in the webpage and the DOM changes). I'm using [chrome.runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) and [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) to communicate between content and pop up scripts.

My question here is: is there any event to which I can listen to in the content script and know when the popup was opened? Or even better, is there a best practice for updating the popup based on tab DOM changes?

Cheers.

Comment: you also directly load script file in html

Answer (score 1):

In your popup page, include the following js

```
window.onload = function() {
    //popup was opened, do what you want
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the  [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers?hl=en).Use 'MutationObserver()', it provide a mechanism for a web page or an extension to get notified about changes made to the DOM.

Code snippet below is how to instantiate DOM mutation observers:

```
new MutationObserver(
function callback
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the Tabs permission you can run a script when the extension's Popup has opened:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    // Run the following code when the popup is opened
});
```

Just remember that the code above has to be run in a background script.

Comment: This is not supported. `onClick` cannot be used with a popup. It says so also in the docs
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action/#event-onClicked